# No response for service from lat & long to address - Yahoo Geo Service

Tags: yahoo-api

I have used Yahoo Boss Geo service.
Today, I realized that one of service, converting latitude & longitude to address, is not working.
Opposite version (address to latitude & longitude) is working fine.

I could use this service at least 2 month ago without any problem.
I don't know why this suddenly happens.

Does anyone have the same issue or know something about that ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read about this issue [here](http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/ysearchboss/conversations/topics/5691).

Hopefully this will solve your problem, as it seems like most people have hit this issue with the new, unannounced latitude/longitude coordinate pair format required for the reverse geo call.

Why Yahoo hasn't told us about this is beyond me. It has actually broken in production for a few of us and they haven't even replied to the thread yet.